# Does YQL (Yahoo Query language) support custom delimiters for CSV?

Tags: yql, delimiter, csv

I know [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) can query `CSV` (comma separated values) format text files.

But often there are text files in just the same simple format but which use a delimiter other than `,` (comma). Tab-delimited text files are quite common for instance. Next most common seems to be the pipe character `|`. In my case I'd like to query a file delimited by semicolon `;`.

I believe other tools that handle `CSV` often have options for other delimiters. I'm pretty sure Yahoo Pipes has such an option. What about Yahoo Query Language?

**Is there a way to query delimited text files in YQL with a delimiter other than `,`?**

If not is there a bug or feature request to add support for custom delimiters or a way to add such support myself?

(My use case is the data published by the Unicode consortium which is many flat files delimited by `;`. The master file being [`UnicodeData.txt`](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt).)

Comment: Please add some constructive criticism to accompany the close vote so I can learn what questions not to ask or how to word them better etc.

Comment: I voted to close, because the question IMHO is not constructive for the wider audience here on stackoverflow. The question is very specific to your needs, and only your needs.

Comment: Hmm that's surprising. I'm pretty sure Yahoo Pipes has support for other delimiters. From other questions under [tag:delimiter] and [tag:delimited-text] it seems that at least tab and pipe are very common alternatives to CSV. I'll re-word to emphasize all delimiters and deemphasize semicolons and UnicodeData.txt

Comment: The answer is still no; the `csv` data table does not support specifying a different delimiter character.

Comment: @salathe: I wasn't expecting the change in wording to change the answer, just to help the question to stay around longer and help other people rather than being closed or deleted. (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to query semicolon-delimited text files with YQL?

Not with any existing data tables. It would not be difficult to create your own data table, with which you could parse the file in any way you like. There is lots of existing JavaScript code to parse delimited files that you can make use of.

> If not is there a bug or feature request to add support for delimiters other than comma?

Not that I am aware of; though this is mostly because I am unaware of any public-facing bug tracker or ticket system for the YQL platform.

Comment: I never got into creating my own data tables because it looked like a lot of reading and a steep learning curve when I've got a long list of tons of other stuff I also want to learn... I thought they were made in XML but you make it sound like I can make it in JavaScript? `UnicodeData.txt` is huge and I've tried to load and parse it with JavaScript before and it just crashes the browser on my poor 2G ram netbook )-:

Comment: Data tables are [defined in XML](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql_dev_guide.html), but can [execute JavaScript code](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-execute-chapter.html).

Comment: I've been reading a lot more about YQL and especially how the Open Data Tables work. I'm ready to start experimenting but it seems I can't make a test one with the YQL console but that I need to make it and put it on the net somewhere and reference by URL when I query it. But does Yahoo provide any place to host these Open Data Table XML files? I don't have a domain or a server etc.

Comment: There is an editor available, linked from within the console. It saves your tables in [Y!'s Sherpa cloud storage infrastructure](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-cloud-chapter.html). Have a read of these articles from the YQL blog: [YQL Editor](http://www.yqlblog.net/blog/2011/10/21/yql-editor/) and [New enhancements to the YQL editor and console](http://www.yqlblog.net/blog/2012/03/01/new-enhancements-to-the-yql-console-and-editor/).